# Nullable and typed dataset, is there a generator somewhere?

Tags: .net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Trying to use a typed dataset with nullable fields...

As been the case since the dawn of time, the typed dataset generator of visual studio does not support nullable types.

Is there, somewhere in the net, a generator for a properly typed dataset?

Comment: The dotnet typed dataset can handle nullable fields. in xsd-file you can use `msdata:AllowDBNull="true" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Entity Framework instead of typed datasets? Older technology isn't updated as quickly as newer.

Comment: Not mature enough for what, exactly? Why do you specifically need typed datasets?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember why... I only remembered to not use EF until .NET 4.0 based on what I read a while back.

Comment: There are enhancements in 4.0, but it's quite sufficiently mature.

Comment: I'll have a look at EF again then. Do you know if EF allows to use a DataSet as input as our closed-source vendor library we use returns a dataset?

Comment: Wait. I was suggesting you use EF instead of datasets.

Comment: Exactly. But my input is not from a database but from a never-connected disconnected dataset coming from a vendor library.

Comment: I don't know whether EF would work for your situation. Maybe, since it's now possible to create a DataReader over the contents of an existing DataTable. But you'd have to create your EF model without a database, and I don't know if that's supported.

Answer (score 0):

EF can map to templated stored procedures which is much more than zero control over sql execution